# Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working properly in Dell Inspiron N5110

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, dell, inspiron

Recently i have upgraded my PC to Ubuntu 14.04. At first everything is fine. I get connected to WIFI and internet too. After some time the internet connection goes off while i am still connected to internet. So i have to turn OFF the WIFI and again turn it ON to get internet connection. After some time same problem repeats again.

Please help.

The output of `sudo lshw -c network` is as follows:

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 18:03:73:9b:42:80
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:54 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f3204000-f3204fff memory:f3200000-f3203fff
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 4c:80:93:0a:62:02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-39-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:57 memory:f7a00000-f7a01fff
```

Comment: Can you please tell us more about how it isn't working properly? It obviously connects as you have an IP address. Does it drop? Slow? Or what?

Comment: Sorry, i mistakely deleted the details while editting. Now i have added the details.

Comment: Would you also show us: dmesg | grep iwl Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Centrino Wireless-N 1030 which uses the `iwlwifi driver`.

Open the file `iwlwifi.conf` using the command

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Now, add the following line at the end and save

`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

Reboot and check whether the wifi is working.

Comment: i haved added the output of sudo lshw -c network, can u please suggest.

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. I just followed as u said. Can u tell me what it actually does. I dont know whether it solved or not. I am testing it.

Comment: It force disables the 802.11n protocol which sometimes causes problems with the open source drivers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am testing whether the problem still exists or not. I will reply later on.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that some Dell computers are packed so tight and run so hot that the wifi cards flake out.  Try using a cooling pad for a while or use an external usb wifi adapter.  If the problem persists, then it's probably not an overheating problem, but if it is, you need to know now as it will shorten the life of your laptop.